# CSS not loading in Firefox or IE. Works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I've created a simple church directory in which I edited the CSS to change one of the default Map Markers to one of my own. The issue that I am having is that the Map marker is displayed correctly on Chrome and Safari but not Firefox IE or Edge.

[copticchurch-directory.org](http://copticchurch-directory.org)

[image]

Code

```
 /*
Theme Name:     Listify Child
Theme URI:      http://astoundify.com/themes/listify
Template:       listify
Version:        1.0
*/
.job_listing-rating-wrapper,
.map-marker-info .rating,
.single-comment-rating,
.star-rating-wrapper {
    display: none !important;
}


.type-job_listing.style-grid .job_listing-entry-footer {
    display: none;
}
.ion-information-circled
{
  content: url(http://copticchurch-directory.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Map-Marker1.svg);
}

.ion-ios.information-circled
{
  content: url(http://copticchurch-directory.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Map-Marker1.svg);
}

.ion.md.information-circled
{
  content: url(http://copticchurch-directory.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Map-Marker1.svg);
}
```

Comment: You are required to post all code that shows the problem here, not a third-party site that can change or disappear tomorrow.

Comment: Your site redirects to a WordPress login.

Comment: Steps: 1) Copy and paste the code into the text box  2) Highlight all of the code  3) press Ctrl and K at the same time. Wallah you have added code to your post. Please edit your post and do so, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the use of the `content` property on regular elements. Use instead the `background` property, which will have better cross-browser support.

Change the following:

```css
.ion-information-circled {
    content: url(...);
}
```

Into this:

```css
.map-marker .ion-information-circled::before {
    content: "";
    background: url(...)
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eyvetdz4/2/

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sampson. However I need to override the CSS from the default map marker. So I will just edit the text and change content to background?

Comment: You should still be able to override the styles.

Comment: So it would be like this... Correct? ion-information-circled { background: url(http://copticchurch-directory.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Map-Marker1.svg); }

Comment: Close; your `ion-information...` should start with a `.` to indicate it is a class.

Comment: Right.. I just miscopied it. Now that I know what to do, if you have the time, could you mind explaining to me as why it works in Chrome and Safari but not other browsers. I assume it had something to do with the link you posted however I still am unsure about what that exactly means.

Comment: The `content` property was originally [added for pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/generate.html#content); Chrome went one step further and made it work for regular elements as well. If this answers your question, please consider accepting the above answer.

Comment: It now shows the original map marker with image behind it.

Comment: When I add the background element, I would leave the ones as is (current code) and then just add it as new code, correct?

Comment: @abbanoob I would change all relevant code to use `background` instead of `content`; it's better to stop using `content` unless you're dealing with a pseudo element.

Comment: Thats what I figured. However, when I did that Sampson, it returned the default map marker with my image behind it. Weird

Comment: @abbanoob The issue is likely with conflicting styles; change your selector from `.ion-information-circled` to `.map-marker i.ion-information-circled::before`, and `content: ""` to it as well. I'll update the answer above too.

Comment: Your answer should be that only chrome has support for `content` property on regular elements. `background` is not the same (it won't set the size by default) and you should at least set the no-repeat option... Also, your fiddle is misleading, your `.pseudo` is not a pseudo element. https://jsfiddle.net/eyvetdz4/4/ And finally, `content` on pseudo-elements (which is the only way defined in the specs) has better support than svg images...